# linux system call hijacking invalid arguments

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I redefined system call using this way:

```
 long my_sys_munmap(unsigned long addr, size_t len)
 {
    PR_DBG("addr(%p) len(%lu)\n", (void *)addr, len);
    .........................


 static int my_make_page_rw(unsigned long addr)
 {
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    if(pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW)
            pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
 }

 static int my_make_page_ro(unsigned long addr) 
 {
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
 }


void my_ioc_patch_munmap(void)
{
    my_make_page_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
    orig_sys_munmap = sys_call_table[__NR_munmap];
    *(sys_call_table+__NR_munmap) = (void *)my_sys_munmap;
    my_make_page_ro((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
}
```

But after that I get the following trace line in my_sys_munmap:

```
 addr(91) len(449989154)
```

It means that the first parameter is number of system call (91). What is prototype of my_sys_munmap in real? I can't get appropriate addr and len.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot asmlinkage directive

```
asmlinkage long my_sys_munmap( unsigned long addr, size_t len)
```

Answer (score 0):

What kernel is this? What architecture (i386?)? Have you tried disassembling the function you are replacing to see how it accesses its arguments?

Comment: x86 Linux 3.14.37 #15 SMP, asmlinkage directive solves the problem